# OS X Lion: Authorization Plugins

Tags: macos, login, authorization

I tried to install an authorization plugin on mac OS X 10.7 that previously worked on Snow Leopard but all I'm getting is a white screen with the cursor. Did something happen to authorization plugins in Lion? Is there a way to fix this?

PS. Something definitely changed considering the way it looks now.

Comment: Not according to [Apple's revision history](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/AuthorizationPluginRef/AuthorizationPluginRef_revHist/revision_history.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001432-CH203-DontLinkElementID_18). Are you sure you built it for the right architecture (x86_64 and i386)?

Comment: Yes this plugin previously worked on a machine running snow leopard in both x86_64 & i386. It stopped working when I upgraded to Lion i.e. the machine is the same

Comment: What do the logs say then?

Comment: SecurityAgent: Problem during create from: (file)
file is the name of where the code for the plugin is located

Comment: Seems the plugin is failing to initialize (http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2005/Nov/msg00001.html). Without knowing more about what the plugin does, it's hard to diagnose further than that. It may well be that the plugin infrastructure hasn't changed, but the plugin requires some other part of OS X that has changed - or it may be as simple as the plugin not being able to access a resource it needs (lacking permission to a file or such).

Comment: the login plugin replaces the default plugin, it doesn't do much, it logs you in.

Comment: I did some research and I found out that plugins having a GUI shouldn't be set as privileged.

Comment: @VxJasonxV the link @ IngmarHupp brought up regards login plugin privilages, my privilages are correct since GUI shouldn't be set to privilaged; i.e it didn't solve my problem >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all the custom GUI from the plugin solved the problem